# Application Cannot Locate Data Directory

Tags: macos

On MacOS, I am getting an error message on for an application where it says "Failed to locate data directory:/Applications/data.

I have absolutely no background in coding, but have discovered the idea of a PATH. Do I need to create a new PATH for this application, or is that completely off the mark?

Comment: This is an application bug.  The application is installed in some subdirectory of Applications, and its data directory should be underneath that.  What application is this?

Comment: It is called GaussView